# Group by with many columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I see a lot of code, which seem to be autogenerated with some drag and drop tool and I see this pattern alot:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, sum(col10)
from Table
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
```

Often there is perhaps multiple joins too. So my question is: What do you think they author of such code was trying to accomplish and what is code like this a symptom of? So I am thinking to rewrite these (perhaps with window functions or joins), but just want to to understand what the cause of such code is...

More clarity: if I show you this code, what do you think the problem is? The results are correct (I guess), the problem is performance.

Edit (extra): I know how group by works, since some are mentioning things like: you need to group by all the columns in your select that are not aggregates.

My own analysis: I think many of the columns are just labels, and most of them can we determined by one or two main columns. That is col3 could be the same as col4 just presented slightly different. I.e. I think the problem is that the data is denormalized before the group by, but say number of distinct groups is the same, say, with two columns, then it is better to perform this group by and then join the remaining columns.

Comment: First, whenever I see a join and sum() together I would question its correctness first. That sum() would only work if and only if it is a 1-to-many relation. Better you should do the sum() first and then join the result. Other than that having many columns in a group by is OK, after all all non-aggreate columns must be included in the group by (though it is ugly and questionable, with a join -1-to-many- it is understandable).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, thanks. But the result are correct since the code is running everyday. I guess my problem is that I suspect a combination of e.g. two columns enough for the aggregates, and the rest is perhaps better to join instead of group by with many columns. Also there are no keys defined on the tables so difficult to see what kind of join I am dealing with...

Comment: It might be for a column-based authority? Just a guess. There may be a filter function that gets this script and return only authorized columns, Some users can only view only col1 and col2 based, but some users col1, col2 and col3,.etc.

Comment: If it is correct, then nothing is wrong with multiple columns, may be you missed in my comment "all non-aggreate columns must be included in the group by".

Comment: @ Yes performance is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the `sum()` provided in this specific example has nothing to aggregate on and is exactly the same as simply selecting that column (in this example). The only way a sum can work is to provide some kind of aggregate data. But that's not your question.

Often, these kinds of queries are developed to support some kind of report. Perhaps a monthly totals report or similar. The list of possible culprits is pretty large. Products like Crystal Reports for example allows a report developer to drag and drop columns on to a report designer, change it's display function to SUM or COUNT, and then the Crystal Reports software automatically generates a SQL query under the hood that will supply that report with the necessary data to generate that report. Start by asking around if anyone is developing reports, and what they are using.

Performance will depend on the complexity of the columns being included in the selection, the size of the table (number of rows), the total length of all columns on the table, and whether or not all the selected columns are included in an index. For example, if one of the columns is a varchar(max), then regardless of the actual length of the data in all returned rows, that will be a heavy query and perform poorly.

Some shops are able to improve performance on reports by first developing some sort of background or nightly job that crunches all the numbers, trims unnecessary or large columns, and dumps the tidied-up results into some 'reports' tables. Then the report developers can target those tables to produce their reports instead of forcing the report to run those long queries on demand every time a user clicks on the report button.

Perhaps it is obvious, but the reason all those fields are referenced in the *group by* clause is simply because they are listed on the *select clause* along with an aggregate function (sum) and must therefore be listed in the group by. Otherwise SQL Server will return an error like

```cs
"Column 'Table.col1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Comment: Thanks, some good info, but I feel my problem is not solved. Don't you think the long list in the group by is just labels for perhaps one or two of the columns in the group by? I don't know the data but data is denormalized before the aggragate and therefore the long list of columns in the select list. I would say maybe normalize the data, have a simple group by and them join the remaning columns.

Comment: That is if one can always determine the values of col3-col10 based on col2 for example them it would be better to rewrite the query to a join after the "real" group by This is just my hypothesis for now I will have to test it...

Comment: @xhr489 The long list in the group by matches exactly the list of fields in the selection, minus the field that is already an aggregate. That is required and will error otherwise because SQL Server needs to physically group rows together in the specific field order listed in the group by in the process of calculating the SUM since the fields are mentioned in the selection. In other words, this sum is specifically a sum of the distinct combinations of columns you select, grouped in the specific field order specified in the group by.